# Refresh fragment from adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have ListView with items in my fragment. Every item has counter for example

Item 1 - 4
Item 2 - 5
On the top of the fragment I have textView with sum of all elements : sum - 9. I can delete Item with click on image on the item row. In adapter (getView()) it goes like this :

```
final LinearLayout delete = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout);
                    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mParts.remove(part);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

The item is being removed from list but counter doesn't change value - for example Item 2 was removed but counter still shows 5. I update it in onResume() method and it works but only if I leave fragment and come back to it. I try to write update method in fragment and use it in adapter - I created constructor with fragment :

```
public PartAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, InvActivity mActivity,InvFragment mFragment) {
        super(context, resource,objects);
        this.mParts = objects;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.mActivity=mActivity;
        this.mFragment = mFragment;
    }
```

but when I call fragment.something I get null point exception :/ How can I refresh fragment/counter textView from adapter ? I also tried to set fragment again but it doesn't work.

Part of my adapter (it's quite long)

```
public class PartAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private OnUpdateListener listener;
    public interface OnUpdateListener {
        void onUpdate(String text);
    }

public void setOnUpdateListner(OnUpdateListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}

private List<Part>mParts;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private TextView mPartName;
public CheckBox mState;
private ImageView mActionArrow;
public static final String TAG = PartAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int CAM_REQUEST  = 1313;
private InvActivity mActivity;
private AdapterCallback mAdapterCallback;
private TextView mCounter;
private ImageView mDelete;
private InvFragment mFragment;
public boolean shouldScan = true;

private final byte[] pal = new byte[]{
        (byte) 0xDA, (byte) 0xAD,  // const
        (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x31, // com
        (byte) 0xe7, (byte) 0x64 //last

};
private final byte[] readId = new byte[]{
        (byte) 0xDA, (byte) 0xAD,  // const
        (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x6f, (byte) 0x69, // com
        (byte) 0xec, (byte) 0x6e //last


};
private UsbManager usbManager;
private UsbDevice device;
public List<String> codes;




public PartAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, InvActivity mActivity,AdapterCallback callback) {
    super(context, resource,objects);
    this.mParts = objects;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mActivity=mActivity;
    this.mAdapterCallback = callback;
}
public PartAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects, InvActivity mActivity,InvFragment mFragment) {
    super(context, resource,objects);
    this.mParts = objects;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mActivity=mActivity;
    this.mFragment = mFragment;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null)
        convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.part_item,parent,false);
    mState = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state_chb);
    mDelete = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.delete_car);
    mDelete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    final Part party = mParts.get(position);
    if(party.isScan() || party.getType().contentEquals("2")) {
        mState.setChecked(true);
    } else if (!party.isScan()){
        mState.setChecked(false);
    }
    if(party.getType().contentEquals("2"))
        mDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    if(mParts.get(position).getClass().isInstance(new Part())) {
        final Part part = (Part) mParts.get(position);
        mPartName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.car_name_tv);
        mState = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state_chb);
        mPartName.setText(part.getName());
        mActionArrow = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_action);
        mCounter = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.car_count_tv);
        mCounter.setText(part.getQuantity());
        if(!part.isScan()) {
            mState.setChecked(false);
        } else if(part.isScan() || part.getType().contentEquals("2")) {
            mState.setChecked(true);
        }

        mActionArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_context_menu);

                final LinearLayout delete = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout);
                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int totalSum = 5;
                        int partValue = 2;
                        mParts.remove(part);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if(listener != null){
                            listener((totalSum - partValue).toString());
                        }

                    }
                });
                LinearLayout photo = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.photo_layout);
                photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent();

                    }
                });
                LinearLayout note = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.note_layout);
                note.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        final Dialog noteDialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                        noteDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        noteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_note);
                        final EditText noteET = (EditText)noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.note_et);
                        if(!part.getNote().contentEquals("null"))
                            noteET.setText(part.getNote());
                        Button save = (Button)noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
                        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                part.setNote(noteET.getText().toString());
                                noteDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        noteDialog.show();
                        Button cancel = (Button) noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                noteDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });

                LinearLayout values = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.values_layout);
                values.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        final Dialog noteDialog = new Dialog(getContext());
                        noteDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                        noteDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_note);
                        final EditText noteET = (EditText)noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.note_et);
                        noteET.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                        Button save = (Button)noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.save_button);
                        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                part.setQuantity(noteET.getText().toString());
                                noteDialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        noteDialog.show();
                        Button cancel = (Button) noteDialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
                        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                noteDialog.dismiss();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }


    return convertView;
}
```

and from my activity :

```
public void onUpdate(String value){
        mCountTV.setText(value);
    }

private void createAdapter() {
    adapter.setOnUpdateListner(this);
}
```

}

Comment: try to add interface in your adapter than catch delete callback in your fragment and update textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow a process like below.

In your `PartAdapter` set a listener which will implemented in Fragment used to update value of `sum` text view.

```
class PartAdapter {
    private OnUpdateLitener listener;

    public interface OnUpdateListener {
        void onUpdate(String text);
    }

    public void setOnUpdateListner(OnUpdateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    // in your getView() method
    final LinearLayout delete = (LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout);
                delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        mParts.remove(part);
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(listener != null){
                            listener.onUpdate(String.valueOf(totalSum - partValue));
                        }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

In your fragment

```
class MyFragment {

    private OnUpdateListener listener; 

    void onAttach(Activity activity){
        if(!(activity instaceof PartAdapter.OnUpdateListener)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Must implement OnUpdateListener");
        }
        listener = (PartAdapter.OnUpdateListener) activity;

    }

    private void createAdapter() {
        PartAdapter adapter = new PartAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.part_item, mParts, mActivity, new AdapterCallback() {
            @Override
                public void onMethodCallback() {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onMethodCallback: ");
                }
            });
            adapter.setOnUpdateListener(this);
            mPartsLV.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

In your activity

```
class MainActivity implements PartAdapter.OnUpdateListener {

    public void onUpdate(String value){
            textView.setText(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I did exactly as You describe but have no response in fragment :/

Comment: Share your fragment and Adapter class those you just tried.

Comment: I edited my post. The problem is also at line                                 listener((totalSum - partValue).toString()); - toString is marked as cannot resolved. totalSum and partValue I set up as default to check if it works :)

Comment: Where is your text view to show total sum? In activity or in Fragment? How did you set `onUpdateListener` of `PartAdapter`?

Comment: In activity. I've got asynctask to download all items from API and then check counters , sum them up and display. Also, I check counters of existing items in "onResume().

Comment: Then you have to implement `OnUpdateListener` in your activity and pass that reference to your `PartAdapter`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120684/discussion-between-md-sufi-khan-and-bartos).

Comment: Could you help mi with these, please. I'm totally lame with interfaces :/